# Bash String Interpolation wget

Tags: string, bash, interpolation, interpretation

I'm trying to download files using wget and for some reason I think I'm encountering some problems with string interpolation. I have a list of files to be downloaded that I have successfully parsed etc (no small feat for me) and would like to incorporate these into a for loop wget statement combo which downloads these files en masse.

Please forgive me the URLs won't work for you because the password and data have been changed.

I have tried single and double quotes as well as escaping a few characters in the URL (the &s and @s which I presume are at the marrow of this).

```
   list of files

   files.txt

   /results/KIDFROST@LARAZA.com--B627-.txt.gz      
   /results/KIDFROST@LARAZA.com--B626-part002.csv.gz   
   /results/KIDFROST@LARAZA.com--B62-part001.csv.gz
```

`wget` statement works as a single command

```
   wget -O files/$i "https://tickhistory.com/HttpPull/Download?           user=KIDFROST@LARAZA.com&pass=RICOSUAVE&file=/results/KIDFROST@LARAZA.com--N6265-.txt.gz"
```

but a loop doesn't work

```
   for i in `cat files.txt`; do  
       wget -O files/$i "https://tickhistory.com/HttpPull/Download?  user=KIDFROST@LARAZA.com&pass=RICOSUAVE&file=$i"
   done
```

Comment: Apart from the `for` vs `while` problem, your code looks fine. How does it break? Do you get an error message?

Comment: /6319-report.csv.gz: No such file or directory
/6264-confirmation.txt.gz: No such file or directory

Comment: despite these messages I know the files are there and, moreover, my path is "correct" (but obviously something is up).

Comment: The error message seems to be saying you have lost the `/results` prefix somehow.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Main issues was "`files/$i"` instead of `"files$i"` (see comments)

Don't use a for-loop/cat for reading files, use a while/read loop. Less problems with buffer-overflow/splitting/etc...

```
while read -r i; do
  wget -O "files$i" "https://tickhistory.com/HttpPull/Download?  user=KIDFROST@LARAZA.com&pass=RICOSUAVE&file=$i"
done < files.txt
```

Also make sure you quote variables to prevent expansion/splitting errors. Also not really sure why you're doing `files/$i`, since `$i` has full path.

Comment: Correct but tangential; unlikely to actually solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @tripleee I think either some weird expansion or the fact that files/$i (which becomes e.g. files//results/KIDFROST@LARAZA.com--B627-.txt.gz)  doesn't make any sense is reasonably likely to solve the problem here. Though agree would help to have more info on error.

Comment: files/$i would be where i want to save the downloads. many thanks for considering my problem.

Comment: @ChaseCB Yes, but since the paths in your input file already start with a `/`, it will expand to e.g. `files//results/KIDFROST@LARAZA.com--B627-.txt.gz` which can never exist. If you do have a `files` subdirectory then you probably want `wget -O "files$i" ...`

Comment: thanks again the "files$i" worked.......i sincerely appreciate your help if you ever write a book or become a tutor let me know.